# Useclasses without making new instances

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to take a string in my mainpage and put it inside my class so I can get it in the next window. My Class is simple and looks like this:

name: Spreadsheet

```
    private string itemType;

    public string ItemType
    {
        get { return itemType; }
        set { itemType = value; }
    }
```

I can change it just fine if I make a new instance, but that will remove everything inside it - I don't want that. I Call the class using this line:

```
private Spreadsheet ss = new Spreadsheet();
```

When I call this method I make a new instance  `new Spreadsheet()` which incorrectly puts all the strings into null. How can I avoid this?

Comment: mark the string and the property as _static_.

Comment: I think you might be looking for the static keyword.

Comment: I think you may want to share resources between views(or windows). I suggest singleton or  shared service (using MEF)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. From the vague description it sounds like all you really need to do is pass the string from the existing window to the new one (your "next window"). But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates how your windows relate to each other and when you want the data to be passed, it's not possible to provide a good answer. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: its rly not that much to type but sure I add the extra 1 line to the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tyler Day said

> I think you might be looking for the static keyword. –  Tyler Day

That fixed my problems
making the private string itemType into private static string itemType was what I missed out :)

To explain why is that static fields are class-level variables that are per-type rather than per-instance

Comment: That's just the definition of static members... it's what they're for (didn't realize this was 1.5 years old!).